# addClass to link on click, then on scroll fix said link to top

Tags: jquery, click, addclass, scrollto

I have an unordered list of links that act as filters for content below.

Link 1
Link 2
Link 3
Link 4

On click of *any* link, the class "active" is added to the link clicked. This works perfectly as it is.

Link 1
Link 2
Link 3 (active)
Link 4

But once I scroll down the page, that link goes out of view, so I want the "active" link to stick to the top by adding another class "fixednav".

Link 3 (active) + (on scroll I want *this* active link to stick to the top)

**I basically need to combine these two with the active-click fiddle being first:

http://jsfiddle.net/m35dB/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/zq9hd/**

How would I write this?

I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" for the "active" class. It doesn't exist yet because I haven't clicked any of the filters.

Filter code:

```
$('#filters a').click(function(){

    if( $(this).is('.active') ) {
       // don't do anything while class is active
    }
    else {
        $('#filters a').removeClass('active'),
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Scroll code:

```
function fixDiv() {
    var $div = $(".active");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
        $('.active').addClass('fixednav'); 
    }
    else {
        $('.active').removeClass('fixednav');
    }
}

$(".active").data("top", $(".active").offset().top);
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

Comment: Where is this line in relation to the rest of the code? `$(".active").data("top", $(".active").offset().top);`? It might be good idea to set up a fiddle to show us exactly what you have at the moment. I have a feeling this line is only being set once and not being reset when a link it clicked.

Comment: See my answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving `$(".active").data("top", $(".active").offset().top);` to inside your click function like this:

```
$('#filters a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.is('.active'))
    {
        $('#filters a').removeClass('active').removeData("top");
        $this.addClass('active').data("top", $this.offset().top);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're thee bomb dude, that works perfectly, thank you! Also thanks for showing me how to use an If without an Else.

Comment: No Worries, you may want to check that `$div.length > 0` in your `fixDiv` function, because if a link hasn't been selected the same uncaught error will occur, `$('.active')` will return no elements when a link hasn't been clicked. Change `if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top"))` to `if ($div.length > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top"))`

Answer (score 1):

Well, `$('.active')` returns a set of elements, not a single element.

Try use something like `$('.active:first')`.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - upon clicking a filter link, it adds the class "active" to only the link clicked. That part works fine. The part I'm having trouble with is adding a class to an element that is defined _after_ being clicked.